# LINQ On DbContext.Set()

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, reflection

So, basically I am trying to get a `DbSet` returned from entity name (string). This is how far I have gotten:

```
var customers = db.Set(Type.GetType("App.Model.Customer, 
                                     App.Model, 
                                     Version=1.0.0.0, 
                                     Culture=neutral, 
                                     PublicKeyToken=null"));
```

But then I cannot perform other LINQ like `Any()` or `Single()`. Why is that and how can I change it to do so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Querying against DbContext.Set(TypeVariable) in Entity Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481685/querying-against-dbcontext-settypevariable-in-entity-framework)

Comment: @Adrian Seems like you understand the problem. Mind briefly explaining it here?

Comment: @Md.lbrahim what in the linked question did you not understand? It seems as though that question and answer explains this issue pretty well..

Comment: To summarise, can't use Linq on DbContext.Set(TypeVariable) because it doesn't return DbSet<TEntity> but a DbSet meaning there is no type that can be inferred to use with Linq methods. You can instead use DbContext.Set<TEntity>() an invoke it as per the given answer which  injects your type using reflection. You will then be able to use Linq.

Comment: @Default I did not, I am afraid. I don't get why would I be concerned with `Local` and what is `IActionTarget`? It would help if you could explain briefly here please.

Comment: @Adrian I get that I can use `DbContext.Set<TEntity>` to use Linq but I am getting my type as string, like I showed above. Because of which cannot use `DbContext.Set<TEntity>` and had to settle for `DbContext.Set()`.

Comment: @Md.lbrahim, have a closer read of the accepted answer. It takes an input of Type which you already have from `Type.GetType("App.Model.Customer, App.Model, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")`.

Comment: IActionTarget is an interface that the other question's poster has made his models implement so that he has some properties that he can access with his Linq queries. Without it he would have to do a lot more work with reflection since the properties of the loaded type is only known at runtime, and therefore he wouldn't be able to write a Linq queries that compiles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The non-generic overload of [`DbContext.Set`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679544(v=vs.113).aspx) returns an equally non-generic [`DbSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset(v=vs.113).aspx). One of the interfaces this class implements is `IQueryable`, again, non generic. That's the reason why  it can't serve as input to any of these LINQ extension method that are defined on the generic type `IQueryable<T>`.

So in fact, if you still want to use LINQ, you only postpone the moment when you have to convert to a generic `IQueryable`. You *could* do...

```
var customers = db.Set(Type.GetType(...)).Cast<Customer>().Where(c => ...)
```

...but then of course you lose the whole point of defining the type dynamically, at runtime.

Once you start dynamically, you have to continue dynamically. One way to do that is by adding [`System.Linq.Dynamic`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) to your project.
Then you can write queries like...

```
var customers = db.Set(Type.GetType(...)).Where("CustomerId = @0", 1);
```

...which will return you the `Customer` (wrapped in an `IQueryable<Customer>`) having `CustomerId == 1`.

You can even use the `Find` method:

```
var customer = db.Set(Type.GetType(...)).Find(1);
```

This will return a single `Customer` instance.

Answer (score 0):

With the requirements you have, no, if the requirements were to change you might be able to work around it. If you get your type as string at runtime, how do you believe you could possibly program against it before you even compile the code?

Static typing need static types to work, you can do some ninja `dynamics` with interfaces to get around part of it, but your question provides no such information.

Comment: All I am getting is the name as string and I have to work against that. If it is required for me to use `dynamic` then so be it. Any working solution is helpful for me at this point. Thanks.

Comment: Then you need some kind of minimal interface you know the type will inherit from? Do you have such?

Comment: I don't currently. But it shouldn't be too difficult. I will just have my models inherit from an interface for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the non-generic IQueryable to a generic (where the generic property is a super class or even just object), e.g.:

```
((IQueryable<object>)context.Set(Type.GetType(...))).Count();
```

This worked for me!