# Visual Studio 2017 on Windows Server 2016 - Cannot inspect lambda LINQ expression on debugging

Tags: c#, entity-framework, debugging, lambda, visual-studio-2017

I hit a very serious fault when debugging a C#, Entity Framework, application.

The evaluation of a LINQ for Entities lambda either on *Watch* or *Inspect* windows yelds: `Evaluation of method System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList() calls into native method System.Diagnostics.Debugger.get_IsAttached(). Evaluation of native methods in this context is not supported.`

This occurs in a, just built from scratch, development Windows Server 2016 VM with Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise. All settings defaulted.

Getting back to an ol'n'gold Windows 2012 VM, same VS, same settings, the fault reoccurs.

The (actually not the very) faulty code's snippet bellow:

[image]

Has anyone there a hint on the problem?

This has to be related to EF, maybe to SQL drivers, or IIS process attachment space.

I've devised a simple scenario with lists and lambda and found no problems:

[image]

Comment: Enable native code debugging? I'm not sure why you need to evaluate what the command is doing, as I know for sure that EF is backed by a robust suite of tests.  You should just be looking at the _result_ of the function, not the function itself. Like in the first example, I would be looking at `fromResult`, not `BaseContext.DbContext.Set<T>(..)`

Comment: Yes, I enabled native code debugging... Actually fromResult has not the result I expect and to devise what's wrong I use the Immediate Window to fiddle with the query and collecting partial results. Of course I could (actually did!) write many var result1 = ..., var result2 = ..., with many scenarios. But that's a tedious proccess and for that, Immediate Window is useless.

Comment: That sounds like a completely different issue. I'm not sure why you're using `DbContext.Set<T>`, but I'm going to guess that is the reason you are having trouble with your queries.

Comment: See the answer here, on why LINQ doesn't work on a `DbSet` returned from 
 `DbContext.Set<T>` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26506619/linq-on-dbcontext-set

Comment: @AdamVincent, thanks for the remark, but that does not apply here. LINQ does not support DbSet, but do support DbSet<T>, as this is the answer at the link you sent. Anyway, the problem is not with LINQ not working (it works...), but with the fact that I'm not able to evaluate changes on the query at the Immediate Window.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I gottit: VS Web Host shan't yield the result of a parameterized LINQ for Entities to the Visual Studio IDE's Immediate/Watch windows whenever a DB access is involved.

Such evaluation yields `calls into native method System.Diagnostics.Debugger.get_IsAttached() ... in this context is not supported`.

In my understanding that's because of DB accesses rely on calls to unmanaged code from SYS drivers.

I'm sure there shall be a set of tweaks on the Source Project, VS Debug, VS Web Hosting, and host IIS Pool settings that circunvent this.

But I could not devise them, either exploring the IDE settings neither googling for it.

So, as I still had a troubleshooting at hand, instead of trying to evaluate something like

`BaseContext.DbContext.Set<SupMedResult>()`
    **`.Where(r => r.CPF == "58243143149")`**
    *`.ToList()`*

I otherwise casted

`BaseContext.DbContext.Set<SupMedResult>()`
    *`.ToList()`*
    **`.Where(r => r.CPF == "58243143149")`**

The way I see this:

- the first approach reached EF decision branches envolving DB schema queries (for graph mapping)
- the second approach rendered a single straight-forward full table fetch

(why a full table fetch did not hit any `native method`? I dunno!)

There forth I was able to do my fiddles and devise where the query was mistaken.

By the way, the actual query was way, WAY, more complex than the one I used in the question and this answer.