# Why can't I pass a lambda expression as a parameter in the Immediate Window in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Note: The question is not "Why can't I use lambda expressions in the Immediate Window?" That is working fine.

When I try to pass a lambda expression as a parameter to a call in the Immediate Window, I get a message back stating "Evaluation of native methods in this context is not supported." Why does this restriction exist and is there a way around it?

For more context, in my main project I have hierarchical data which is occasionally useful to visualize while debugging. To facilitate this, I added a routine that dumps information back to the Immediate Window (via Debug.WriteLine) when invoked, showing the hierarchy (via indentation) along with salient properties of the objects in the hierarchy. Each object has many properties and as I often don't know what I need to see beforehand, I thought it might be neat to add an optional parameter Func<*type*, Object> to my dump routine so that I could highlight a particular term of each object on a given invocation.

In the example code below, I've simplified the hierarchy to a simple collection, but the idea is the same and it reproduces the error.

At the breakpoint, I can issue the following command in the Immediate Window

`collection.DumpData();`

and the output is what I would expect

**Item info: Id = 1, Property = foo**

**Item info: Id = 2, Property = heidy**

However, if I pass a lambda expression such as

`collection.DumpData(o => o.OtherProperty);`

I get the following error:

> Evaluation of method ReproduceImmediateWindowLimitation.ItemCollection.DumpData(System.Func`2<ReproduceImmediateWindowLimitation.exe!ReproduceImmediateWindowLimitation.Item, object>) calls into native method System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsLogging(). Evaluation of native methods in this context is not supported.

This error is not specific to Debug.WriteLine. I get the same basic error if I use System.Diagnostics.Trace or if I collect the output lines and write them to a file.

The same problem happens if I assign the lambda expression to a variable beforehand

```
Func<Item, Object> immediate = o => o.OtherProperty;
collection.DumpData(immediate);
```

The closest thing I could find to this problem on stackoverflow is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51260824/6858247) from Marcus where he attributes the problem to EF internals but given my problem I do not believe this is the case.

Obviously I could get around this problem by adding more properties to the output of my dump routine or via reflection, but those options are a lot less flexible.

Example code:

```
namespace ReproduceImmediateWindowLimitation
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var collection = new ItemCollection
            {
                new Item { ItemId = 1, Property = "foo", OtherProperty = "bar" },
                new Item { ItemId = 2, Property = "heidy", OtherProperty = "ho" }
            };

            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

        }
    }

    class ItemCollection : List<Item>
    {
        public void DumpData(Func<Item, Object> highlightTerm = null)
        {
            foreach (var item in this)
            {
                object highlightTermResult = null;
                if (highlightTerm != null)
                {
                    var temp = highlightTerm(item);
                    if (temp == null)
                    {
                        highlightTermResult = "n/a";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        highlightTermResult = String.Format(">> highlighted term {0} <<", temp);
                    }
                }

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(
                    "Item info: Id = {0}, Property = {1} {2}",
                    item.ItemId,
                    item.Property,
                    highlightTermResult ?? "");
            }
        }
    }

    class Item
    {
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public string Property { get; set; }
        public string OtherProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Update:

To address Seabizkit's point, the use of a collection here is just for example purposes. I can further simplify the code and still reproduce the problem.

`item.DumpData();`

yields

**Item info: Id = 1, Property = foo**

as expected, but

`item.DumpData(o => o.OtherProperty);`

yields

> ReproduceImmediateWindowLimitation.Item.DumpData(System.Func`2<ReproduceImmediateWindowLimitation.exe!ReproduceImmediateWindowLimitation.Item, object>) calls into native method System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsLogging(). Evaluation of native methods in this context is not supported.

```
namespace ReproduceImmediateWindowLimitation
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var item = new Item { ItemId = 1, Property = "foo", OtherProperty = "bar" };

            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

        }
    }

    class Item
    {
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public string Property { get; set; }
        public string OtherProperty { get; set; }

        public void DumpData(Func<Item, Object> highlightTerm = null)
        {
            object highlightTermResult = null;
            if (highlightTerm != null)
            {
                var temp = highlightTerm(this);
                if (temp == null)
                {
                    highlightTermResult = "n/a";
                }
                else
                {
                    highlightTermResult = String.Format(">> highlighted term {0} <<", temp);
                }
            }

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(
                "Item info: Id = {0}, Property = {1} {2}",
                this.ItemId,
                this.Property,
                highlightTermResult ?? "");
        }
    }
}
```

Update 2:
As mentioned in the comment to StriplingWarrior, I tried enabling native code debugging in the project. Also just for grins I tried marking the DumpData method as unsafe (with the /unsafe compiler option). Neither changed the behavior.

Comment: is DumpData a requirement of `: List<Item>` i would not of thought so... so i would say dnt mess with inheriting a List and putting a function in there, rather make an extension that would with that type,  than put normal methods inside the logic of a custom list type, aka why are you inheriting List? if its not a gd reason dnt do it.

Comment: Thank you @Seabizkit I have updated my question to address this.

Comment: Does [enable native code debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-in-mixed-mode?view=vs-2022#enable-mixed-mode-debugging-for-a-managed-calling-app) help?

Comment: Thank you @StriplingWarrior Enabling native code debugging in the project properties did not change the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

this is not an answer just stating that not all code is available to reproduce...

this does **not throw** and results in

```
Item info: Id = 1, Property = foo >> highlighted term bar <<
```

in the console.

```
var item = new Item { ItemId = 1, Property = "foo", OtherProperty = "bar" };

try
{
    item.DumpData(o => o.OtherProperty);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw;
}


System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string Property { get; set; }
    public string OtherProperty { get; set; }

    public void DumpData(Func<Item, Object> highlightTerm = null)
    {
        object highlightTermResult = null;
        if (highlightTerm != null)
        {
            var temp = highlightTerm(this);
            if (temp == null)
            {
                highlightTermResult = "n/a";
            }
            else
            {
                highlightTermResult = String.Format(">> highlighted term {0} <<", temp);
            }
        }
    
        Console.WriteLine("Item info: Id = {0}, Property = {1} {2}",
            this.ItemId,
            this.Property,
            highlightTermResult ?? "");

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(
            "Item info: Id = {0}, Property = {1} {2}",
            this.ItemId,
            this.Property,
            highlightTermResult ?? "");
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct. If item.DumpData is called from Main() with lambda rather than from the Immeditate Window, all is well.

Comment: @sgibson5150 no what i am saying is given the code here... no exception is throw... so either you have namespace mix up or what you have doesn't represent the same. aka start new console, copy past the code above and it should work.... if it doesnt we need more info

Comment: I don't understand your response. This question is about invoking my Dump method from the Immediate Window. I never stated there was an exception being thrown. I used the default _Console App (.NET Framework)_ template to create the project. How could there be a "namespace mix up"? Both examples I posted are the entire contents of the Program.cs file except for the usings, which I did not change. I'd be happy to give you more info if there was any.  :)

Comment: @sgibson5150 apologies i miss understood, ill delete and retry what u actually asking.... "why it doesnt work in Immediate Window"